# writing a formal proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If B is a statement form involving only negation, conjunction and disjunction, and B' results from B by replacing each conjunction by a disjunction and each disjunction by a conjunction,  show that B is a tautology if and only if non-B' is a tautology.

It is clear that if non-B' is a tautology then B is also a tautology.That is because B' is obtained from B by switching the connectors so by applying the negation to B' we obtain B.

I just don't know how to write a formal proof.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's so clear. Consider an arbitrary formula $B$, e.g. $p\lor q$. Then $\neg B' = \neg(p\land q) \equiv \neg p \lor \neg q$. Some assignments of values to $p,q$ make both formulas true; other assignments make one formula true but the other false. You can't say "so by applying $\neg$ to $B'$ we obtain $B$" — we **don't** "obtain $B$". Your 'reasoning' doesn't use any property about tautologies, so why should it work for them and not for arbitrary formulas? More is needed. Toward that end, see the answer :)

Comment: I just started the course and I'm not familiar with all the properties.I also didn't know about De'Morgan's law until I read your proof, I see where I was wrong.Thanks!

Comment: Odd course, if it asks you to prove this nontrivial theorem but doesn't introduce De Morgan's law(s) (which also holds in Boolean algebras, by the way). It seems essential to the proof, and a very important part of why the theorem is true. In actual mathematical reasoning (heck, in general reasoning & argument), De Morgan is used all the time, without mention.

Comment: The course is fine, it introduced De Morgan's but I skipped some content to try and prove my mettle by tackling the problems.

Comment: Ah, ok, good. I like this problem/theorem.

Answer (score 1):

We need a couple of propositions before proving the statement.

First, define another transform $A^{\neg}$ of propositional formulas $A$: $A^{\neg}$ is the results of negating all propositional variables in $A$.
This transform leaves all connectives unchanged — it distributes over $\neg, \land, \lor$. Note that the two transforms commute: $A'^{\neg} = {A^{\neg}}'$.

For example, if $B = (p\lor \neg p)$ then $B' = (p\land \neg p)$ and $B'^{\neg} = (\neg p\land \neg\neg p)$.

**Proposition 1:** $B$ is equivalent to $\neg B'^{\neg}$.

We'll use $\equiv$ to denote logical equivalence. Proof is by induction on the complexity of $B$.

Base case: $B$ is some propositional variable $p$. Then $B' = p$, and $B'^{\neg} = \neg p$, so $B = p \equiv \neg\neg p = \neg B'^{\neg}$.

[$B = \neg A$]:  $B'$ is $\neg A'$, and $B'^{\neg}$ is $\neg A'^{\neg}$. By induction hypothesis (IH), $A\equiv \neg A'^{\neg}$, so clearly $B = \neg A\equiv \neg\neg A'^{\neg} = \neg B'^{\neg}$.

[$B = (C\lor D)]$: $B' = (C'\land D')$, and $B'^{\neg} = (C'^{\neg}\land D'^{\neg})$.
By De Morgan, $\neg B'^{\neg} \equiv (\neg C'^{\neg} \lor \neg D'^{\neg})$. By IH, $C\equiv \neg C'^{\neg}$ and $D\equiv \neg D'^{\neg}$, so $\neg B'^{\neg} \equiv (C \lor D) = B$.

[$B = (C\land D)]$: Similar to the previous case, using the other De Morgan law.

**Proposition 2**: if $A$ is a tautology iff $A^{\neg}$ is a tautology.

Given any assignment of truth values to propositional variables $v\colon Variables\to \{0,1\}$, where $0$ and $1$ represent `False` and `True` respectively, let $v^{\neg}$ be the assignment that "flips" $v$: $$v^{\neg}(p) = 1 - v(p).
$$
Obviously this operation on assignments is self-inverse:
$$v^{{\neg}{\neg}} = v, \tag{SI}
$$
and a bijection of assignments.

For any formula $A$, let $A[v]$ be the truth value of $A$ under the assignment $v$. Clearly, 
$$A^{\neg}[v] = A[v^{\neg}].\tag{*}
$$

By definition, $A$ is a tautology iff for all assignments $v$, $A[v] = 1$. By (SI), $A$ is a tautology iff for all assignments $v$, $A[v^{\neg}] = 1$. By (*), this holds iff for all assignments $v$, $A^{\neg}[v] = 1$, which is true iff $A^{\neg}$ is a tautology.

Now we can prove the statement:

> $A$ is a tautology iff $\neg A'$ is a tautology.

By Prop. 1, $A\equiv \neg (A'^{\neg})$, which therefore is a tautology iff $A$ is. But $\neg (A'^{\neg}) = (\neg A')^{\neg}$, which by Prop. 2 is a tautology iff $\neg A'$ is. This yields the result.